# Can you invoke Lambda Jobs from AWS Batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

When looking at the [params](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_CreateJobQueue.html) required to add jobs to a queue and [create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html) a batch job, it looks like it requires EC2 computeEnvironment settings.  The UI in the AWS console implies the same.

I was wondering if anyone had any luck queueing lambda job types in batch?  Or am I taking serverless too far here :|

Ideally the instructions for the batch computing can be defined in the SFN (it supports it for EC2/ECS jobs)

Use Case:

```
SFN
Lambda -> Lambda[0, 1, ..., n] -> Lambda
```

Comment: The docs suggest that only EC2 On Demand and EC2 Spot are currently supported for compute environments. Does it matter to you that your job would run containerized on EC2 vs. containerized on Lambda (on EC2)?

Comment: No other than if it was containerized on Lambda I wouldn't need to provision a cluster for the instances to run on.  Less configuration